# Spring security cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [SecRole] for property 'secRole'

Tags: java, grails, spring-security

I have these two errors when i update my user with a different role:

`Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [rms.SecUser] for property 'secUser': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]`

`Cannot convert value of type [java.lang.String] to required type [rms.SecRole] for property 'secRole': no matching editors or conversion strategy found]`

Im using the grails spring security plugin.

Here's my controller:

```
def updateSecUserSecRole(Long id, Long version) {
    def secUserSecRoleInstance = SecUserSecRole.get(id)
    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance) {
        flash.message = message(code: 'default.not.found.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), id])
        redirect(action: "listSecUserSecRole")
        return
    }

    if (version != null) {
        if (secUserSecRoleInstance.version > version) {
            secUserSecRoleInstance.errors.rejectValue("version", "default.optimistic.locking.failure",
                      [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole')] as Object[],
                      "Another user has updated this SecUserSecRole while you were editing")
            redirect(action: "listSecUserSecRole")
            return
        }
    }

    secUserSecRoleInstance.properties = params

    if (!secUserSecRoleInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        secUserSecRoleInstance.errors.allErrors.each{
            println  it
        } 

        redirect(action: "listSecUserSecRole")
        return
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.updated.message', args: [message(code: 'secUserSecRole.label', default: 'SecUserSecRole'), secUserSecRoleInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "listSecUserSecRole")
}
```

and here is a snippet of my form fields in the edit gsp:

```
<g:select class="select2-edit" style="width:30% !important;" id="secUser.id" name="secUser" from="${rms.SecUser.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="username" required="" value="${secUserSecRoleInstance?.secUser?.id}" />

<g:select id="secRole.id" name="secRole" from="${rms.SecRole.list()}" optionKey="id" optionValue="authority" required="" value="${secUserSecRoleInstance?.secRole?.id}" />
```

Comment: where it's happening? `secUserSecRoleInstance.properties = params`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov most likely

Comment: any chance that `params` contains `rms.SecUser`?

Comment: @IgorArtamonov what do you mean by that? like this `params.containsKey(secUser)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML form submit send data as charactes (a String), even for `<g:select` tag. And you get `String` for both `params.secRole` and `params.secUser`.

But `SecUserSecRole` expects `SecRole` and `SecUser` instances instead. You cannot assign `secUserSecRole` with strings (that's what you're doing with `secUserSecRoleInstance.properties = params`. also it's insecure), you just need to load actual data and pass this objects instead.

Like:

```
secUserSecRoleInstance.secUser = SecUser.get(params.secUser)
secUserSecRoleInstance.secRole = SecRole.get(params.secRole)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect, in your form, the name should match the id. So,

```
 id="secUser.id" name="secUser.id" 
 id="secRole.id" name="secRole.id"
```

More specifically, the form is submitted with the `name` value rather than the `id`

Comment: this also works. but as igor said its insecure so i combined both of your answers

Comment: yes Igor is right about the security risk. the point I was making is that your param names were being submitted as `secUser` rather than 'secUser.id' and is an HTML thing standar. btw Grails automatically does a lookup if you submit as 'secuUser.id'. As for security, read up 'Data Binding and Security Concerns' in the docs http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#dataBinding, for safer ways to do that.